# Did the Avengers stay to have lunch with Tony?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

When Natasha, Steve, and Scott visit Tony to ask for his help in building a time machine, after Tony refuses, he invites them to stay for lunch.

> If you don't talk shop, you can stay for lunch.

After this it cuts to Natasha, Steve, and Scott leaving. Is there any implication as to whether or not they stayed for lunch? I don't see anything that tells us whether the shot of them leaving is after they had lunch with Tony, or if they refused his offer and left immediately.

While perhaps it is meant as a completely irrelevant detail, knowing that they stayed for lunch would give some insight into the character relationships; how much of a friendship still remained between them at this point.

I'm looking for either in-universe explanations (something about how the scene was shot, if there was an intended implication, etc); or out-of-universe explanations, although it seems unlikely that something like this would have been mentioned or addressed by anyone who worked on the film.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They did not stay for lunch.** In his (in-universe) autobiography Scott Lang describes the encounter:

> Tony interrupted, “That’s right, Scott: I won’t even. I can’t.”
>
> Well, what could I say to that? I remembered with blindingly painful
> clarity those days in prison, just dreaming of getting to bounce my
> little bundle of Cassie on my knee. Reflecting, over and over, that my
> own decisions had snatched that precious, once-in-a-lifetime sweetness
> away. And here I was, effectively proposing that exact path to Tony.
>
> I couldn’t even imagine what I would do if faced with the choice of
> saving the universe or saving my Cassie.
>
> **Moments later, Cap, Nat, and I were headed back to the car,
> empty-handed.** There was nothing left to say. Tony had saved so many
> lives. Now he just wanted a chance to have a life of his own.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Look Out for the Little Guy!* by Scott Lang](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Look_Out_for_the_Little_Guy!)</sup></sub>

Having refused to stay, history does not record if they stopped for drive-thru on their way back to the Avengers Compound.

Comment: Amazing that this would get an official answer many years later! Are these passages from the movie Quantummania? (Out of universe)

Comment: @GendoIkari - Yes. This is the book he does the reading from.

Answer (score 1):

It felt to me that they declined it and left. They didn't seem to be interested in wasting time at that moment and that's why the checked bit Bruce next. Even [reellifebygrace](https://reellifebygrace.com/2019/06/19/the-important-role-food-played-in-avengers-endgame/) seems to conclude the same:

> They talk “quantum physics”  and saving the world, and Tony invites them to stay for lunch. They have to decline and leave to go talk to Dr. Banner.

Comment: I've not idea who *reellifebygrace* is, but they appear to have no connection to the making of the film, nor any special insight to offer us.